# telnet from linux pc to windows pc using python script

Tags: python, telnet

i am trying to telnet a windows pc from linux using python script(pexpect).when i try to connect this error pop's up  **The operation completed successfully...Login Failed** below is my python script.

```
import pexpect,time,sys
from ftplib import FTP
def tel(ipadrr,login,password):

        try:    
                global telconn
                telconn = pexpect.spawn(ipadrr)
                telconn.logfile = open("/tmp/telnetlog", "a") 

                print "connected to telnet"
                print
        except:
                print "telconnnet connection refused"
                print 
                sys.exit() 

        try:
                time.sleep(15)
                #telconn.expect(": ")
                print "username"
                telconn.sendline(login + '\r')
                telconn.expect(":")
                print "password"
                telconn.sendline(password + '\r')
                #telconn.sendline("\r")
                #time.sleep(30)
                telconn.expect(">") 
                print "Authentication Sucesss"
                print
        except:
                print "Authentication Failure"
                print        
                sys.exit()
```

Comment: the parameter for pexpect.spawn() should be an command e.g. telnet 127.0.0.1. why dont use telnetlib module?

Comment: Please post the complete output of running this once. Also @tecjam is correct about supplying the full command to .spawn().

Comment: Hi nolen
 i have already defined  the value def 'tel' inside the below program.
  import telnetftp,ftp,tel
  import pexpect,time,telnetlib
  from ftplib import FTP

  telnetftp.tel("telnet 192.0.0.105","usr","pass@123" .
 i have already tried with telnetlib module but show the same error

Comment: After running my script i am getting this output,if i am running it manually it's running fine
Trying 192.168.0.105...
Connected to 192.168.0.105.
Escape character is '^]'.
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Service 

login: usr
password: pass@123

The operation completed successfully.

Login Failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your password is not entering via script. Try with,

```
telconn.sendline(password + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

@vish..its already answered the same question..plz verfiy the same

```
import pexpect
import time,sys
telconn = pexpect.spawn('telnet 192.168.0.105')
time.sleep(20)
telconn.logfile = sys.stdout
telconn.expect(":")
time.sleep(20)
telconn.send("user" + "\r")
telconn.expect(":")
telconn.send("user@123" + "\r")
telconn.send("\r\n")
time.sleep(20)
telconn.expect(">")
```